# CALayer not showing in UIImageView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimageview, core-animation

I have a UIImageView with an image already set, and try to add a CALayer as a subview. It works (sublayer count rises from 0 to 1) but nothing happens on the screen. Even if I try to set the layer background to black or set hidden to 'No'..

```
 CALayer*layer=[[CALayer alloc]initWithLayer:anotherUIImageView.layer];

[myUIImageVIew.layer addSublayer:layer];

[[myUIImageView.layer.sublayers objectAtIndex:0] setHidden:NO];
[[myUIImageView.layer.sublayers objectAtIndex:0] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set some bounds to the layer and assign a colour, so you can see it

```
CALayer* layer = [CALayer layer];
layer.bounds = CGMakeRect(0, 0, 10, 20);
layer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor greenColor] CGColor];
[myUIImageVIew.layer addSublayer:layer];
```

Also, from the [documentaion](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) of `[CALayer initWithLayer:]`:

**Note**: Invoking this method in any other situation will produce undefined behavior. **Do not use this method to initialize a new layer with an existing layer’s content.**

Comment: Yes! Thanks Davyd, I must assume that for once I had not read the whole Apple documentation on this topic. Time was missing, so i lost it! thx again